# Are local references cleared by `DetachCurrentThread`?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a program that calls the JVM by using the [Java Native Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/). The program is a server. It has to handle multiple requests and stay online for a long period of time.

In order to avoid memory leaks caused by local references, I found that in a single-thread implementation I can call [`PushLocalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#PushLocalFrame) before handling each request and [`PopLocalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#PopLocalFrame) after handling each request, so that local references are cleared.

Now, I would like to handle multiple requests concurrently. I plan to can call [`AttachCurrentThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread) before handling each request and [`DetachCurrentThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#DetachCurrentThread) after handling each request, using a different `JNIEnv` for each request.

My question is: do I also have to call `PushLocalFrame`/`PopLocalFrame` before and after handling each request, or are local references already cleared by `DetachCurrentThread`? I can't find any documentation of this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to pop local frames when the thread detaches:

> If you attach a native thread with AttachCurrentThread, the code you are running will never automatically free local references until the thread detaches

Source: ["JNI Tips - Local and Global References"](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#local_and_global_references)
.